# C++ Data Flow Software/Library

Tags: c++, data-visualization, dataflow

I want to write a data flow application so I want an open source (or even commercial) software/library to take idea or code from it and use as building block and write my application upon it.

Can anyone point me to a C++ written data flow software/library?

My system is Windows but it is better to be cross-platform, and my application is used for real time functionality so speed is important.

I've tested QNodeEditor but it seems very simple and hasn't many capabilities.

Comment: I guess there might be quite a lot of such libraries. Maybe you could specify a bit more what exactly you want to do? An example maybe.

Comment: It is unclear if you want some kind of data flow computation library implemented in C++, or if you want a data flow analysis of C++ code.  There's a faint hint in the phrase "... and write my application in it", which suggests the former.  But if that's the case, why is C++ necessary? There are many data flow langauages/frameworks out there.